Use variable inside the same page by clicking on table row for display another table in php maybe JS
I'll start by saying that I'm not a programmer but I enjoy making some pages/scripts that can be useful to me. And I enjoy it.
I'm compiling a PHP/JS/HTML page for a player ranking, but I got stuck trying to save an ID of a row of a table to be able to reuse it as a variable (the procedure is a bit more cumbersome).
Basically, there are two tables. The first is a list of players in order of score. I would like to make it so that clicking on a player's row generates a table with the games played in the lower part. And it works OK. The problem is that clicking on the single row through the $_GET method updates the page and I would like that not to happen. When clicking on the single player row, the row is highlighted and I would not like this "highlighting" to be lost.
I managed to make the additional table appear in the modal via ajax following and studying some tutorials. Thank you for the suggestions. Now however the new table appears to me by clicking only on the button, I would like to make it appear by clicking on the whole row and (as an alternative) make it appear below (not in a new modal)
thanks
<?php
      require_once('./php/config.php');

      $q_classifica = "SELECT * FROM giocatori ORDER BY punti DESC";
      if($r_classifica = $conn->query($q_classifica))
      {
          $indice=1;

          echo '<div class="box-class1 roboto-bold">
          <table style="width: 380px; height: 60px;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="scrolldown prova">
          <thead><tr>
          <th style="width: 60px"></th>
          <th style="width: 205px"></th>
          <th style="width: 86px"></th>
          <th style="width: 29px"></th>
          </tr></thead><tbody>';
          
          while ($row1 = $r_classifica->fetch_array())
          {
              echo '
              <tr onclick="getIndex(this)">
              <td style="width: 60px"><a href="https://wa.me/' . $row1['cell'] . '?text=Ciao...quando%20potresti%20giocare?"><img style="width: 17px; height: 19px;" alt="ball" src="ball.png"></a>   ' . $indice . '</td>
              <td style="width: 205px">' . $row1['nome'] . '</td>
              <td style="width: 86px">' . $row1['punti'] . '<button class="button_round" id=' . $row1['ID'] . '>Dettagli</button></td>';
        
                  $infortunio = $row1['infortunio'];
                  if($infortunio==si){echo '<td style="width: 29px"><img style="width: 30px; height: 22px;" alt="infortunato" src="ambulanza.png"></td></tr>';}
                  else{
                  echo '<td></td></tr>';
                      }
                  $indice++;
          }
          echo "</tbody></table></div>";

      }else{
          echo "Errore impossibile eseguire la query $q_classifica. " . $conn->error;
          }
?>

      <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">GIOCATORE</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">

            
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
              
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('button').click(function(){
                  id_player = $(this).attr('id')
                  $.ajax({url: "select.php",
                  method:'post',
                  data:{player_id:id_player},
                success: function(result){
                  $(".modal-body").html(result);
      }});


              $('#myModal').modal("show");

          })

      })
    </script>

select.php
<?php
        require_once('./php/config.php');
        if(isset($_POST["player_id"]))
        {

        $output = '';


        $a_giocatore = "SELECT nome FROM giocatori WHERE giocatori.id = '".$_POST["player_id"]."'";
        $result = $conn->query($a_giocatore);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $giocatore= $row['nome'];
            } 
            


        $output .= '
        <H2><div style="text-align: center;" class="roboto-black-italic box-giocatore1">' . $giocatore . '</H2></div>';




        $q_partita = "SELECT * FROM partite WHERE (giocatore_1 = '$giocatore' OR giocatore_2 = '$giocatore') AND (vittoria = '$giocatore') AND (punteggio IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY data DESC";
        if($r_partita = $conn->query($q_partita))
            {
                $output .= '
                <table style="text-align: center;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="vinte">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 105px;"><br></th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 105px;"><img alt="up" src="vi.png"><br></th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 70px;"><br></th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 70px;"><br></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>';
            
                while ($row1 = $r_partita->fetch_array())
                {
                    $data = $row1['data'];
                    $timestamp_data = strtotime($data); // converte data in formato leggibile a video, cercare modo di mettere nomi in ITA
                    $formato = 'j M Y'; 
                    $resultd = date($formato, $timestamp_data); // converte data in formato leggibile a video, cercare modo di mettere nomi in ITA
                    $output .= '
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="roboto-regular-italic"><font size="1">' . $row1['giocatore_1'] . '</font></td>
                            <td class="roboto-regular-italic"><font size="1">' . $row1['giocatore_2'] . '</font></td>
                            <td class="roboto-regular-italic"><font size="1">' . $row1['punteggio'] . '</font></td>
                            <td class="roboto-regular-italic"><font size="1">' . $resultd . '</font></td>
                        </tr>';
                }
                $output .= '
                    </tbody>
                </table>';
            }


        $q_partita2 = "SELECT * FROM partite WHERE (giocatore_1 = '$giocatore' OR giocatore_2 = '$giocatore') AND (sconfitta = '$giocatore') AND (punteggio IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY data DESC";
        if($r_partita2 = $conn->query($q_partita2))
            {
                $output .= '
                <table style="text-align: center;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="perse">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 105px;"><br></th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 105px;"><img alt="up" src="sc.png"><br></th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 70px;"><br></th>
                            <th style="vertical-align: top; width: 70px;"><br></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>';
                    
                while ($row1 = $r_partita2->fetch_array())
                {
                    $data2 = $row1['data'];
                    $timestamp_data2 = strtotime($data2); // converte data in formato leggibile a video, cercare modo di mettere nomi in ITA
                    $formato2 = 'j M Y'; 
                    $result2 = date($formato2, $timestamp_data2); // converte data in formato leggibile a video, cercare modo di mettere nomi in ITA
                    $output .= '
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="roboto-regular-italic"><font size="1">' . $row1['giocatore_1'] . '</font></td>
                            <td class="roboto-regular-italic"><font size="1">' . $row1['giocatore_2'] . '</font></td>
                            <td class="roboto-regular-italic"><font size="1">' . $row1['punteggio'] . '</font></td>
                            <td class="roboto-regular-italic"><font size="1">' . $result2 . '</font></td>
                        </tr> ';
                }
                $output .= '
                    </tbody>
                </table>';
            }

        echo $output;
        echo '</br><div class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>';
        unset ($giocatore);

        }

I also tried via JS to generate a variable that I then don't know how to handle in PHP within the procedure (click table row? ID). Using JS to identify the ID I can't then use the variable inside the loop.
I think I understood that with PHP I always have the page reload and therefore I should use JS. I was hoping to solve it in another way because with JS I am not very confident, I rarely use scripts that I find ready on the web.

Two options: You send all your data to the client to begin with, so that JS can handle the rest completely on its own there; or you make an AJAX/fetch request in the background, to specifically request the details for the chosen record, and then update your current document with those.

Please be warned that your SELECT statements are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked. Also, is this a PHP problem or a MySQL problem?

Thanks, I'm currently studying SQL injections.
https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection
I'd like to solve with PHP.. I'm having trouble with JS

"I'm having trouble with JS" - that sounds strange, you haven't shared any JS code so far. Please also add all clarification to your question by editing it

If you don't want it to update the whole page when you click, then you need to use JavaScript. If you're struggling with JavaScript right now, that's hard, but it's worth taking the time to get good at it, because it's vital to writing any kind of modern web application. You can do your task only with PHP if you like, but you have to accept that it will refresh the whole page anytime the user clicks to update or show data, because it means submitting a (non-AJAX) request to the server in order to execute the PHP script.

Aside from functionality, I recommend to everyone who does this. Don't mix HTML/JS and PHP in one file. This is very unreadable and very vulnerable for bugs. As said here before, look into AJAX or a similar technology to handle PHP data inside your JS.

I managed to make the additional table appear in the modal via ajax following and studying some tutorials
Now however the new table appears to me by clicking only on the button, I would like to make it appear by clicking on the whole row and (as an alternative) make it appear below (not in a new modal) thanks

You can handle clicking on a table row, no problem - the JS "click" event works on almost any HTML element. Just attach the handler to the table row element instead of a button. And making the table appear somewhere else is just a case of which element you run the .html function on

Why not? If you're using AJAX to fetch data then you shouldn't need to reload anything. It's a bit unclear what your specific problem is right now. Also, if you need further help, [edit] your question to ensure we can see your current code and have a clear description of the current problem.

I managed to use the click on the row in the script
by inserting the class "mia" on the click
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mia').click(function(){
id_player = $(this).attr('id')
$.ajax({url: "home.php",
method:'post',
data:{player_id:id_player},
success: function(result){
$(".modbody").html(result);
}});
and the additional table appear in a new "div" in the usual page
but the first table appears twice when I click (maybe url: "home.php" reloads the first table again and inserts it below?)

Well now you are sending a request to home.php in the ajax script instead of select.php, so of course it will load all of home.php again. In the code in your question, the ajax sends to select.php, which only returns the specific data needed to load the table, not the entire page all over again. That was a lot more logical. It doesn't  make any sense to send the ajax request back to the main script...it should go to a separate script which only loads what is relevant at that time.
